# Geodesic deviation second covariant derivative

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, vector-fields, geodesics

Suppose that $V$ is a vector field tangent to a family of geodesic curves. Furthermore suppose that there exists another vector field $T$ , where T is the tangent vector field that determines how far the geodesics are from each other. I know how to compute an expression such as $\nabla_VV$ however I do not know how to compute an expression such as $\nabla_T\nabla_VV$. How would I compute this second covariant derivative?

Comment: You have $\nabla_V V = \mu V$ for some $\mathbb C$-valued function $\mu$ (which is zero if you take affine parametrization). So $\nabla_T \nabla_V V  = \nabla_T (\mu \nabla V) $ ($=0$ with affine parametrization)

Comment: I know that the expression equals 0 but how can I show that it equals 0?

Comment: By definition, if the geodesic have an affine parameter (such as proper time in GR), $\nabla_V V = 0$. So its derivative (covariant or not) must also be zero.